# return DOM in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to write a javascript function to parse a bit of the DOM tree and return a part of it to further parse. Despite stepping through the function which seems to be working fine, the return of the function shows as undefined to the calling statement. Is there a way to fix this?

```
from = entityfromid($(value)[0].getElementsByTagName("O1")[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue).getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

function entityfromid(id) {
$($(xmlDoc)[0].getElementsByTagName("Entities")[0].childNodes).each(function (index, value) {
    if(value.getElementsByTagName('Id')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue == id) {
        return value;
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Please post your actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take the `return` statement out of the `.each()`, and instead return from your `entityfromid` function.

```
function entityfromid(id) {

    var ret_value;

    $($(xmlDoc)[0].getElementsByTagName("Entities")[0].childNodes).each(function (index, value) {
        if(value.getElementsByTagName('Id')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue == id) {
            ret_value = value;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return ret_value;
}
```

Here, when your result is found, it will set the value of the `ret_value` variable, and do a `return false`, which breaks the loop.

Then the `ret_value` is used for the `return` from your function.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't expect returning from there to cause it to not properly return from the function.